# How do I access properties of a Service using an API in WSO2 GREG?

Tags: wso2, soa

I can add and read attributes using the governance API like this:

```
        registry = Util.initialize();
        governanceRegistry = Util.getGovernanceRegistry(registry);

        serviceManager = new ServiceManager(governanceRegistry);

        services = Arrays.asList(serviceManager.getAllServices());
        services.get(2).addAttribute("what", "isthis");
        serviceManager.updateService(services.get(2));
```

However, when I use the WSO2 Governance Registry Management Console and open the service I just added the parameter/value "what"/"isthis", I dont see it in the list of *Properties*.

How do I access the list of *properties* (not attributes) using an API? I have a hard time figuring out how these relate to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve it using following code.

```
List<Resource> paths = getServicePath(registry, "/_system/governance/trunk/services");

 for (Resource service : paths) {
                // we've got all the services here

               Properties props = service.getProperties();
                for (Object prop : props.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println(prop + " - " + props.get(prop));
                }
        }
```

Refer this sample [blog post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/access-wso2-registry) for complete code.

----Added later---

This is more aligned with your code.

```
 Registry governanceRegistry = GovernanceUtils.getGovernanceUserRegistry(registry, "admin");
       ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(governanceRegistry);
       Service[] services = serviceManager.getAllServices();

        for(int i =0 ; i<services.length ; i++){
            Service service = services[i];
            Resource resource = governanceRegistry.get(service.getPath());
            System.out.println(resource.getProperties());
        }
```

Comment: Two follow-up questions: 1. Which class has the method getServicePath? Dont I need to invoke it like this SomeClassInstance.getServicePath(registry,"/...")? 2. Is it not possible to cast from org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.services.dataobjects.Service to org.wso2.carbon.registry.api.Resource?

Comment: 1)This code is extracted from the blog post i have referred. So complete source is there.

Comment: 2) No. So i am adding a more clear code segment which is aligned with your code.